# How to read Gigya Account data through python code?

Tags: python, gigya

I am new to API and development.

Any idea how to read Gigya account details through api, using python?

If I can pass the email address, I want to list down other details, such as UID, First name, Last name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gigya's REST API to get the details of a Gigya account. You can use [accounts.getAccountInfo](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/cab69a86edae49e2be93fd51b78fc35b.html?locale=en-US) Where you can pass the UID of the user and get the profile in the response or you can use [accounts.search](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/b32ce0918af44c3ebd7e96650fa6cc1d.html?locale=en-US), where you can do a query to get the user profile.

You have examples in Python in the links.